# How add text to a cell in Excel 2013 based on the absence of specific words/sentence?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Lets say in **column A** I have cells that contain the following text approximately 25% of the time:

```
"This is a super special cell."
```

I'm trying to find a function that could read **column A** for the above text, and append (at the start of the string) the corresponding cell in **column B** (A25 and B 25, for example) with the following text if the cell in column A ***does not*** contain the "super special cell" text mentioned earlier:

```
"This is not a super special cell"
```

I've googled/tinkered/researched etc. but haven't come up with much. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution gives what you ask in column C.  If you really want to modify column B, you will need a VBA approach.

[image]

The formula in C1 is:

```
IFERROR(IF(FIND("super special cell",A1,1)>0,B1,""),"This is not a super special cell" & B1)
```

`Find` will return a number >0 if found and will throw an error if not.  I used the `If` statement to return contents of B1 unmodified if A1 is a "super special cell".  The false condition of the `If` statement will never be used because of the error, so I just put in `""`.  `Iferror` captures the not found condition and gives you the appended cell value that you requested.